# Call variabile from another class without making new instance [ PHP ]

Tags: php, oop

I have an array in my class "Parse" in this array I have multiple data, it looks like( i show just some important lines here:

```
class Parse
{
    public static $data = array();  

    public function parseXML()
    {
        .
        .
        .
        $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "item" );
        foreach( $items as $item )
        {  
          $keys = $item->getElementsByTagName( "key" );
          $key = $keys->item(0)->nodeValue;

          $values = $item->getElementsByTagName( "value" );
          $value = $values->item(0)->nodeValue;

          //adding login and password to array              
          $data[$key] = $value;

        }       
        $claimNumber = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "ClaimNumber" );
        $claimNumber = $claimNumber->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $vin = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "VIN" );
        $vin = $vin->item(0)->nodeValue;    

        //adding claimnumber and VIN to array
        $data['claimNumber'] = $claimNumber;        
        $data['vin'] = $vin;

        $this->data = $data;
        return $data;
    }
```

So basicly in $data I should have vin, claimnumber and few more things from foreach (to not make you confuse let's ignore data from foreach)

Okey so and now I want to acces this data from another class and method, and I dont want to make new instance of it becuase this will truncate all data which is already in $data from previous used method `parseXML()`
class Rest
{
    public $token = null;

```
public function authorization()
{
    //define enviroment and path        
    $host = enviroment;
    $path = "/oauth/token"; 
    $username = Parse::$data['claimNumber'];
```

This is something which I found in another stackoverflow questions but it return just :`Undefined index: claimNumber` also tryedd to just add `Parse::$data;` with basicly same result.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$this->data = $data;` in `parseXML()` method with `self::$data = $data;`